# Error 404 when trying to access a controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to access a CodeIgniter controller and I'm getting a 404 error. 
In my computer, I can access `.../index.php/apadrinhamentoController/padrinhosPossiveis`

but when uploaded to the server, I can just access the index file, in the 
`site.com/apadrinhamento/index.php` and not `site.com/apadrinhamento/index.php/apadrinhamentoController` (Get 404 error).

`apadrinhamentoController.php` File

```
<?php
class apadrinhamentoController extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
public function index() {
    $this->load->view('apadrinhamento');
}
}
```

`index.php` file is default from CodeIgniter

I'm not using a `.htaccess` on `/apadrinhamento`

Comment: what were necessary settings you have made in  routes,config files would you post code for that

Comment: It could be absolutely anything that you have not shown us.  The `index.php` file would normally be in the www root, not in a subdirectory.  What's in your `.htaccess` file?  What about your `config.php` file?  The various settings in your `index.php` file?  What have you tried so far to solve this yourself?

Comment: The index.php file is the default of CodeIgniter ... I'm not using a .htaccess file on this folder

Comment: That's impossible.  The default `index.php` can't work without configuring a few lines for your particular installation.  It's explained in the documentation.

Comment: I have an installation of wordpress in the root and codeigniter in a subfolder ...

Comment: That's fine, but you cannot just use the default `index.php` file without first editing it.  Just read the documentation... proper installation is clearly explained.

Comment: Are you getting the 404 error page from the server, from CodeIgniter, or from WordPress?  Each one will have its own 404 page.

Comment: From codeigniter ... but when trying to access some link inside the folder of codeigniter that doesn't exists I get 404 error page of wordpress.

Comment: That's because WordPress will control everything on the domain where it's installed.  You'll have to use the root `.htaccess` file to exclude the CodeIgniter directory from WordPress.  In other words, you have several issues here that you need to sort out, and the fact that you're trying to use WordPress at the same time needs to be clearly described in the OP.

Comment: But How Can I do that ?

Comment: You can start by editing the question to properly describe the situation.  The fact that you have WordPress installed is important, so don't you think you should mention it above and tag the question with it?  The proper people will see it and maybe be able to answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should understand, `Codeigniter != CakePHP`. Means you no need to define `controller_name`+`Controller` word.

```
class apadrinhamento extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    public function index() 
    {
        //$this->load->view('apadrinhamento');
        echo 'Im index of your function';
    }

    public function my_method() 
    {
        echo 'I jsut access my_Method';
    }

}
```

and in `config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "";//Default Controller Name
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

and

to access your controller(above)

```
site.com/apadrinhamento/ //this will access index() function
//or
site.com/index.php/apadrinhamento/
```

if you want to access the method inside it(URL Should be)

```
site.com/apadrinhamento/my_method
//or
site.com/index.php/apadrinhamento/my_method
```

> **Note** if you not place `.htaccess` then url should be `site.com/index.php/apadrinhamento/`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in CodeIgniter v3.0 we need to write controller files names starting with capital letters.

Comment: And yet somehow it still worked on your local machine.  Another problem is that in your OP you failed to mention which version of CodeIgniter you're using.  Please review:  [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)